# If $A = \{a,b,c,d\}$, is $\{b,c\} \subseteq \mathcal P(A)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A = \{a,b,c,d\}$, then is $\{b,c\}\subseteq \mathcal P(A)$ ?  I thought the answer was true, but I am not totally sure on that, because I am not sure if it is correct to say that $\{a,b\}$ is a subset of $\mathcal P(A)$, or if $\{a,b\}$ exists in $\mathcal P(A)$.  Can anybody confirm and say way or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{\{b,c\}\}\subset P(A)$ but $\{b,c\}\not\subseteq P(A)$ because in subsets i talk about a set and $\{b,c\}$ is not a set and is an element

Answer (score 5):

$\{b,c\}\in P(A)$ and $\{b,c\}\not\subseteq P(A)$.

Comment: It **could** be true, e.g., if $b=\emptyset$ and $c=\{a\}.$

Answer (score 1):

That is not true. It should be $\{b,c\} \in \mathcal{P}(A)$